# Progressbar in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to add an progress bar to a column like so

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Plant}" Header="Plant" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Area}" Header="Area" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LocationName}" Header="Location" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LocationVersion}" Header="Version on location" />

        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Deploy, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Check to deploy" IsReadOnly="False" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Orders Count" Width="380">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Minimum="0" Maximum="200" Value="{Binding copyToLocationProgress ,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is the ILocation which i'm using:

```
 public interface ILocation
    {
        int LocationId { get; }

        string LocationName { get; set; }

        string Area { get; set; }

        string LocationVersion { get; set; }

        int Plant { get; set; }

        bool Deploy { get; set; }

        string FolderName { get; }

        int copyToLocationProgress { get; set; }
    }
```

This is in the ViewModel

```
public IEnumerable<ILocation> Locations { get; set; }
```

I have also tried it this way

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Deploy progress" Width="380">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <ProgressBar
                                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                                    Grid.Column="0" 
                                                    Minimum="0"
                                                    Maximum="200" 
                                                    Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Locations, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But this gave me this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is
>   not valid for target property.; Value=''
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.Locations; DataItem='DataGrid'
>   (Name=''); target element is 'ProgressBar' (Name=''); target property
>   is 'Value' (type 'Double')

But I can't see the value like on the other columns. Because it's databind to a Grid.

Comment: Please show us how and where you have declared your `OrderCounts` property.

Comment: @Sheridan i have added the missing code and corrected OrderCount to the correct which is copyToLocationProgress which is in the ILocation interface

Comment: @mortenstarck could you show us ILocation implementation?

Comment: @HichemCSharp Where are no implementation for it. Since im using Castle Windsor. So there's no need for implementing it.

Comment: @mortenstarck is Output window showing any errors?

Comment: Then i load the view. The copyToLocationProgress property is zero and during the exercution of the program i just find the rigth ILocation in the list and sets the value. But my main problem is that i can't get the copyToLocationProgress from the List like i do with the rest of the fields.

Comment: @mortenstarck I couldn't understand your problem.

Comment: What happens if you replace the `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `DataGridTextColumn`, just like you did for the other values? Are the values displayed properly? If not, something may be wrong with your data source.

Comment: @gehho it can't. Because the DataGridTextColumn can't contain a ProgressBar, which is what i would like and the source is the correct one, because the rest of the fields are just fine.

Comment: @mortenstarck: I meant, just display the `copyToLocationProgress` value in a normal text column *for testing*. In this case, is the value displayed properly?

Comment: @gehho sorry i misunderstood you. Yes i have tried that, and i worked perfectly. I just updatede the specific location and used the OnpropertyChanged property to display the update and it worked.

Comment: @mortenstarck I just created a simple repro with a dummy implementation of your interface which returns random values. This works perfectly with your first XAML snippet. So, this seems to be correct. The problem must be somewhere else. What do your ProgressBars display? Is their value always 0? Are you sure you do not need any PropertyChanged? Since you say that you do not have any implementation for the interface, you will most likely not have a PropertyChanged event either. That means, property changes will not be propagated to the UI! Where do you set the `copyToLocationProgress` property?

Comment: @gehho The Progress value will start as 0 and go to 100 then copy files is complete. And the checkbox do set the check value i the IEnumerable<ILocation> Locations, and the rest of the fields are displaying the correct data perfectly. And whether if the OnPropertyChange method is used, i think it has to notify the rest of the datagrid that needs to update. Perhaps my problem is that i'm using databinding, which i don't know can change things.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39279/discussion-between-gehho-and-mortenstarck)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TemplateBinding can only be used within a ControlTemplate, you're using it within a DataTemplate. (The fact that the DataTemplate is within a ControlTemplate doesn't matter).

Change your xaml:

```
   <ItemContainerTemplate >
      <Grid>
         <ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Minimum="0" Maximum="200" Value="{Binding CopyToLocationProgress ,Mode=OneWay}"/>
      </Grid>
   </ItemContainerTemplate>
```

and everything should be ok.

Comment: it just complains that the <ItemContainerTemplate> can't resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I am late but use something like this. In the template column you need to use cell template and then use the item container template.

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <ItemContainerTemplate>

                            <Grid>
                                <ProgressBar></ProgressBar>
                            </Grid>
                        </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```